# Loop outputs the menu of my C program twice

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, menu, do-while

So on Code Review I made a calculator that does the normal operations like addition etc ([Here was the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91881/simple-calculator-in-c-v2)). Anyway I followed some of the advice and updated the program. However the menu of the original program works fine, it outputs the menu once when the user runs the program and when they finish doing a calculation the program would then loop back to the start and out the menu once again. Like any other infinite loop does. But I decided to make the program from scratch again but this time the program outputs the menu twice after the user does the first calculation. I've tried doing `for(;;)` instead of the do-while loop but I get the same issue. I have no idea what's gone wrong, would be greatly appreciate if someone could fix this for me and so I don't come across this issue again.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getNumbers(float *, float *);
float addition(float, float);
float subtraction(float, float);
float multiplication(float, float);
float division(float, float);

int main(void)
{
    do
    {
        float num1, num2;
        char choice;

        puts("\nEnter number or letter from below\n\n"
             "\t1. Addition\n"
             "\t2. Subtraction\n"
             "\t3. Multiplication\n"
             "\t4. Division\n"
             "\tQ. Quit program");

        printf("\nEnter choice: ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);

        if(choice == 'q' || choice == 'Q')
        {
            puts("\nQuitting program...");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(choice < '1' || choice > '4')
        {
            puts("\nInvalid input");
        }
        else
        {
            getNumbers(&num1, &num2);

            if(choice == '1')
            {
                printf("\n%.2f + %.2f = %.2f\n", num1, num2, addition(num1, num2));
            }
            else if(choice == '2')
            {
                printf("\n%.2f - %.2f = %.2f\n", num1, num2, subtraction(num1, num2));
            }
            else if(choice == '3')
            {
                printf("\n%.2f * %.2f = %.2f\n", num1, num2, multiplication(num1, num2));
            }
            else if(choice == '4')
            {
                if(num2 == 0)
                {
                    puts("\nDivision by zero");
                }
                else if(num2 != 0)
                {
                    printf("\n%.2f / %.2f = %.2f\n", num1, num2, division(num1, num2));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                puts("\nInvalid input");
            }
        }
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}

void getNumbers(float *num1_ptr, float *num2_ptr)
{
    printf("\nEnter first number: ");
    scanf("%f", num1_ptr);

    printf("\nEnter second number: ");
    scanf("%f", num2_ptr);
}
float addition(float num1, float num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
float subtraction(float num1, float num2)
{
    return num1 - num2;
}
float multiplication(float num1, float num2)
{
    return num1 * num2;
}
float division(float num1, float num2)
{
    return num1 / num2;
}
```

Comment: You might want to try to add ``printf``s around the code to see what it's doing.

Comment: try `scanf("%c", &choice);` change to `scanf(" %c", &choice);` for skip newline.

Comment: Works, weird how it did that. In the other program I did the `scanf("%c", &choice);` but didn't output the menu twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be your `scanf` is the problem?
Try this:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

The way you had it `scanf` could leave newline which would be consumed in the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

the reason the program outputs the menu twice

(including the "invalid input" message)

is because the values are being entered via the return key

(not much choice about that)

The code is not emptying stdin before looping back to the top of the loop.

suggest adding just before the end of the loop:

```
while( getchar() != '\n' );
```